# Jenkins job DSL: extract branch with last commit in groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl, bitbucket-server

I'm using Jenkins for running jobs automatically. I'm using also Bitbucket Server as a  version control system.

I set up my Jenkins job DSL on any changes in my Bitbucket repo(on each commit) using some groovy script for job creation:

```
job(jobName) {
  steps {
    // Doing some staff. Need name of branch where last commit was done
  }
  scm {
      git('ssh://git@<my_git_host>/<my_project>/<my_repo>.git', '**')
  }
  triggers {
    bitbucketPush()
    scm ''
  }
```

So, when I'm doing some commits into `my_repo` this job runs and I want to extract name of branch where commit was done. Is it possible to do it somehow?

P.S. on Jenkins side(UI) I can see name of branch for current execution, but I have no idea how to extract it on groovy side.

Comment: Are you looking for the plan to run on the branch where the commit happens? Or just a specific branch every time there is a commit on it?

Comment: @KeepCalmAndCarryOn, I'm interesting on each branch from my repository where commit happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the branch information will be stored in the Environment Variables with ID "GIT_BRANCH" for each build, So there are lot ways to extract it.

you can simply add the following script

```
job(jobName) {
  steps {
       shell('''
               echo $GIT_BRANCH
             '''.stripIndent().trim())
            }
  scm {
      git('ssh://git@<my_git_host>/<my_project>/<my_repo>.git', '**')
  }
  triggers {
    bitbucketPush()
    scm ''
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! Are these variables documented somewhere?

Comment: Ya just click on the build number, it will open build info page. In that page left side you can see  Environment Varribles tab